# Heroku Web Won't Update on Refresh

Tags: heroku, web-applications

I have a very simple plaintext web app on a free, unverified account (which is how I would prefer to leave it). It only has 1 web dynmo and works perfectly after I update the git repository, but when I refresh the app's page (without updating the git), it does not update the content of the website.

How do I make it rerun the command on each page refresh (or even at all)? I understand that ideally I would use 2 web dynmos so it would never go to sleep but the delay on awakening isn't detrimental in my case. I just don't get how `heroku ps` can show a running web dynmo without doing anything new.